# How to center-align and adjust font of the index reference in a TOC using memoir?

Tags: memoir, makeidx

I'm using the memoir class and have a TOC that is center aligned. I adjust the chapter formatting and shown in my MWE below, but the index seems to follow some of the formatting but not all of it? E.g., it's not showing a leader, which is correct, but it's left-justified and the wrong size?

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\ordinal\relax

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\HUGE\textit{Contents}}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{\hspace*{10pt}\huge#1\cftparfillskip\par}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{}
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\hfil\Large\emph{#1}\hfil\strut\huge\par\nopagebreak\hfil}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{The First Chapter}
Here is some text.\index{text}
\chapter{The Second Chapter}
Here is some text.\index{text}

\backmatter
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar to this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\ordinal\relax

\makeindex

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\HUGE\textit{Contents}}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}

\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\par\centering\huge}
\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{{\Large\itshape #1}\par}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{~~#1\par}

% remove some grouping
\patchcmd\l@chapapp{%
  {\cftchapterfont {#1}}%
}{%
  \par\cftchapterfont #1%
}{\typeout{l@part patched}}{\typeout{l@part patch failed}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{The First Chapter}
Here is some text.\index{text}

\backmatter
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: It’d be better to patch to `\par\cftchapterfont {#1}%` in case someone for instance wants to make it lowercase